# Lyapunov function utility in stochastic optimal control

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, stochastic-calculus

The article [**Optimal strategy of vaccination and treatment in an SIRS model with Markovian switching** by (X.Mu, Q.Zhang)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019MMAS...42..767M/abstract) studies necessary and sufficient conditions on near-optimal controls.

In both necessary and sufficient conditions (starting by **Theorem 3.4**'s proof), a Lyapunov function (or as it appears to me) is introduced as $V$.

I want to understand first the utility (or use) of the Lyapunov function in such case. All I know is that it's used to study some aspects of solution's stability in ODEs and deterministic systems. And second, if this function verifies the conditions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function) (such as continuous first derivatives), why the Lyapunov function chosen by the authors doesn't verify the conditions.

If I'm getting the concept in a wrong way, any reference or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MO!  It seems this question can be improved by (i) pointing to the precise location (theorem/lemma/proposition) where the Lyapunov function is presented and (ii) embedding a link to that paper.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Hello. Got it !

Comment: $V$ there stands for value function (defined right before Def. 2.1) not Lyapunov function. The value function satisfies the HJB PDE $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=\mathcal{L}V$ where the operator $\mathcal{L}$ is defined between equations (1)-(2). These notations are standard in stochastic optimal control.

Comment: @AbhishekHalder Thanks for the reply but the $V$ is not the cost function. In fact if you go to the indicated theorem's proof, you'll find that they'll introduce a whole new function $V$ with $ln$ and sums. That's the one I mean.

Comment: As far as I understand, equation (36) is a "candidate" for value function on which generator $\mathcal{L}$ is applied. I do not think it has anything to do with Lyapunov function because the RHS of (36) is not even a positive definite function.

Comment: @Hamdiken No, $V$ is not a Lyapunov function. It is a function which is used in order to obtain a bound on the term $I_2$. The idea by carefully choosing that function $V$, differentiating along the trajectories of the system and tuning properly, we can get a bound on $I_2$ through integration.

Comment: @KBS So the choice of $V$ is not based on some stability theorem as I understood. Thanks a lot ! One more thing just to understand, can Lyapunov functions be used also in such case ? Like for finding upper bounds and so on ?

Comment: @Hamdiken A Lyapunov function is a function that satisfies the Lyapunov condition. You can differentiate any function along the flow of a system to do whatever you want. Those function are not necessarily Lyapunov functions, but rather test functions.

Comment: @KBS I get it now. Thank you again !